# Why is a differential a dual basis vector (i.e. why $dx^i \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j} =\delta^i_j$)?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I have been learning about differential forms, but do not understand exactly why a differential $dx$ forms a dual basis to the basis $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$.

For example, expand a vector $\vec{w}$ as $\vec{w}=w^je_j$, $i=1,2,\ldots, n$ on an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ with coordinates $x^i$. Why is it that
$$dx^i\vec{w}=dx^iw^je_j=w^i$$
In other words, why is is true that
$$dx^ie_j=\delta^i_j$$
I am used to thinking of the differential $dx$ as a differential displacement in the $x$ direction, and not as a dual basis. Is it possible to reconcile the two notions?

Comment: Isn't this just definition?

Comment: It might help to think of $x^i$ as a function that maps a point to its $i$th coordinate.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, for any real-valued function $f$, the differential form $df$ is a map that takes a derivative operator to that derivative of $f$.

So $dx^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}=\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^j}$ by definition.

Comment: Could you expand a bit more as to how you go from your first sentence and definition to the second one? I'm used to thinking of $df$ as $df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}dx^j$, where Einstein notation is used and $f=f(x^1, x^2, \ldots, x^j)$. I don't understand how the equation follows from the definition.

Comment: Alright, I think I may now understand it. Let me know if the following reasoning is correct. So, $df$ on a manifold $M$ with tangent space $T_qM$ at $q$, is defined by $df_q:T_qM\to\mathbb{R}$ and $df_q(L_q)=L_q(f)$, where $L_q\in T_qM$. Thus, $dx^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}=\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^j}=\delta^i_j$, and so $dx^i$ is the dual basis to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$.

Comment: @Zachary That's exactly right. And there is no Einstein summation notation used (yet) in my answer, as we aren't contacting anything. It's merely the partial derivative in the direction of $x^j$, and the function $x^i$.